# PHP / HTML using "../" for subdomains

Tags: php, html, file, subdomain, subdirectory

I am making a website which has a sub-domain but some of the resources are shared between the main domain and the sub-domain such as the style sheet. Instead of duplicating the file into *http://sub.domain.com* from *http://domain.com*, is there a way to use "../style.css" to obtain it from the folder level up? I know I can if I access the website via *http://domain.com/sub* but not *http://sub.domain.com* because it looks in the folder above.

To clarify, this is not just for stylesheet, something like an include.php file for variables and functions would need to be included in the sub-domain from the main domain.
Many thanks.

Comment: Now, this is probably not the most helpful advice, but have you considered links or some sort? You know, 'duplicate' the .css sheet, by putting a link to the actual subdomain folder.

Comment: if I decided to later change the structure of the website, this may then no longer work. I have thought about using "http://domain.com/style.css" in the <link> tag but I want it to be done dynamically - I though PHP maybe about to do it with the _SERVER global somehow

Comment: php files should (hopefully) be only included from the local filesystem...that has nothing to do with the subdomains, which is over a network.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use the full path of the stylesheet?

It is not possible to go out of the document root with HTML.

Comment: It's not just the stylesheet. It could included .php files that I need to use from the main domain.

Comment: php files should (hopefully) be only included from the local filesystem...that has nothing to do with the subdomains, which is over a network.

Comment: @StefanDunn: If it's in a subdomain, and you need to include common PHP files, something is probably wrong with your structure. Also, you can provide full paths in PHP's `include(` as well.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can access the contents of the main domain folder from the subdomain.

Comment: A file in sub.domain.com using something like "../style.css" will be looking for a file below sub.domain.com which doesn't exist but does when accessed via domain.com/sub/.

Comment: a sub-domain is a folder inside the main root of your site therefore the sub-domain folder is below the main folder. just like if you were to access a file in the sub-domainn folder from the main folder you just use `/subfolder/style.css`